# How to make existing configmaps use kubernetes secrets

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

I am a newbie to kubernetes and I have to implement kubernetes secrets for existing configmaps with passwords hardcorded.

I have 2 configmaps for each pod, 1 settings.yaml and other settings_override.yaml. I have to make override file read environment variables where I have kept base64 secrets. 
I have created secrets and can see them in pods after printenv.

Kindly suggest me how can I make my settings_override.yaml file read these environment secrets.

Note: if I just remove the key:value pair from settings_override.yaml file then it is picking value from settings.yaml but not from my env variable.

Settings and setting_override file for reference:

`apiVersion: v1 
 data: setting.json: | { 
 "test": { 
 "testpswd": "test123",
 "testPort": "123", 
  }, 
 }`

`apiVersion: v1 
 data: setting_override.json: | { 
"test": { 
"testpswd": "test456", 
"testPort": "456", 
}, 
}`

Comment: can you add your `settings.yaml` and `settings_override.yaml` for better understanding, remove anything which is confidential.

Comment: Hi, please find example below:


``apiVersion: v1
data:
setting.json: |
    {
  "test": {
      "testpswd": "test123",
      "testPort": "123",
      },
 }
``

***********************************************************

`apiVersion: v1
data:
setting.override.json: |
    {
  "test": {
      "testpswd": "test456",
      "testPort": "456",
      },
}
`

For settings_override file , i have created test_testpswd and test_testport as env variable. I want to remove these hardcoded values but unfortnately its not picking the env variable but taking values from setting file.

Comment: @Here_2_learn -- i have added details in the above comment. Sorry for the bad formatting of code.

Comment: It is bad formatting of code because you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58834384/edit) instead of posting updates into comments; the comments are very space limited and (as you have seen) do not format code blocks well. Please move the comment content into your question

Comment: @AnuThakur I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do. But I can ensure you that you want to update a configmap, you will need some other app that is able to read your pod's env and perform update operation on configmap.

Answer (score 4):

As per my knowledge what you're trying to accomplish is not possible in Kubernetes.

A general reminder: `Secrets` are for confidential data and `ConfigMaps` are for non-confidential data.

You can't import a `Secret` into a `ConfigMap` or vice versa.

You can however fill environment variables from a `Secret` (`secretKeyRef`) or a `ConfigMap` (`configMapKeyRef`) like this:

```
    env:
    - name: FOO
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: nonconfidentialdatahere
          key: nonconfidentialdatahere
    - name: BAR
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: confidentialdatahere
          key: confidentialdatahere
```

So I suggest you read the port from your `ConfigMap` and the password from your `Secret` into an environment variable in your pod/deployment declaration and then start whatever service you want by passing those environment variables.